# How to define the default grammar for new file extensions

Tags: atom-editor

I'm opening files in Atom with a new file extension, a file extension that is not recognized by any of the existing grammars (i.e. Plain Test, C, C#, etc.).  How can I associate my new file extension with one of the already-available grammars?

Success is being able to open a file with my new file extension and have Atom default to my chosen grammar automatically.

I tried the suggestion but Atom bounced it back at me:

```
customFileTypes:
  "source.fs": [
    "*.seedsource"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

For personal use, you can register a custom file type in the Atom config file (`config.cson` by default).

Here's a minimal example of what `config.cson` might look like. Make sure to insert the `customFileTypes` part at the correct indentation, since CSON files are indentation-sensitive.

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "source.c": [
        "*.custom-extension"
      ]
```

If you want to share this configuration with other users, it's probably better to create a package that contains a grammar file (e.g. `grammars/custom.cson`):

```
fileTypes: [
  "custom-extension"
]
patterns: [
  {
    include: "source.c"
  }
]
scopeName: "source.c.custom"
```

In both cases, `example.custom-extension` would be opened with C syntax highlighting.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it. [Read how to do that and why it helps others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/259968).

Comment: The field where the extension is written is the extension ONLY, without the proceeding period. So instead of `"*.custom-extension"` it would be only `"custom-extension"`. I couldn't get it to work until that change. See https://flight-manual.atom.io/faq/sections/how-do-i-make-atom-recognize-a-file-with-extension-x-as-language-y/